# Prove $\sqrt{x^2 + y}\ge x$, when $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove when 
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y} \geq x,$$ when $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: For non negative $x,y$ $$\sqrt{x^2+y}\geq\sqrt{x^2}=x$$ As @WillieWong stated, you can't prove strong inequallity beacause $y=0$ will be a counterexample

Comment: I have. I am sort of new to inequalities but they told us that you can't square both sides of inequalities. That's why I am stuck

Comment: That makes sense. Wow. I never thought of that.

Comment: As stated the statement is false, actually. When $x = y = 0$ the inequality is not strict.

Comment: Corrected the question.

Comment: you may square both sides of an inequality if they're both non-negative

Comment: note:  the body has an extra word "when," which the title does not have

Comment: "Prove when A when B and C".  That sentence doesn't make sense.  What are we proving.  If we assume that $\sqrt{x^2 +y } \ge x$  and $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ then what statement are we trying to prove.  Do you means "Prove *THAT* $\sqrt{x^2 + y} \ge x$ WHEN $x \ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$"(true)  or did you mean "Prove WHEN $\sqrt{x^2 + y} \ge x$ THAT $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$" (false), or did you mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

Um, what are your axioms and props?

Axiom:  If $a > b$ then $c + a > b+a$.  So as $y \ge 0$ we have $x^2 + y \ge x^2$.

You should have proven at a proposition at some time that $x^2 \ge 0$

You should have proven at some point that if $c \ge 0$ there is a unique $b\ge 0$ so that $b^2 = c$ and we call that $b=\sqrt c$, so by definition, if $x \ge 0$ then $\sqrt {x^2} = x$.

And you should have an axiom that if $c > 0$ and $a < b$ then $ac < bc$.  With that axiom we con prove that for non-negative values that $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}= \sqrt{d}$ and $\sqrt{e} > \sqrt{f}$ $$\implies a=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}<\sqrt a \sqrt b < \sqrt b \sqrt b = b,  c=\sqrt c \sqrt c=\sqrt d \sqrt d = d, e=\sqrt e\sqrt e > \sqrt e \sqrt f > \sqrt f\sqrt f = f$$ so for non negative values $\sqrt a \le \sqrt b \iff a \le b$.

So that's it.

$x^2 \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ so $x^2 + y \ge x^2 \ge 0$ so $\sqrt{x^2 + y}\ge \sqrt{x^2} = x$.

That's all there is to it.

=====

Alternatively you can do a proof by contradiction.

If $\sqrt{x^2 + y} \not \ge x$ then the only other options is $\sqrt{x^2 + y} < x$.  But by definition $0\le \sqrt{x^2 + y}$ so

$\sqrt{x^2 + y}*\sqrt{x^2 + y} < \sqrt{x^2+y}*x < x*x$ so

$x^2 + y < x^2$ so

$y < 0$

But we we told $y \ge 0$.  So $\sqrt{x^2 + y} \not{\not \ge} x$ so $\sqrt{x^2 + y} \ge x$.